# group by rollup: identify subtotals rows

Tags: apex, soql, group-by-rollup

in this Apex code,

```
List<AggregateResult> agr = [
    SELECT LeadSource, Rating, COUNT(Name) cName
    FROM Lead
    GROUP BY ROLLUP (LeadSource, Rating) 
];

for(AggregateResult r : agr){
    System.debug(r);
}
```

i get a result like

[image]

My question is how to distinguish a row that represents a record, and one with the subtotals (underlined in purple)? I could include the id in the query, but then i'd have to also include in the grouping and then add a subtotal calculation. And checking if the row has LeadSource and Rating as nulls, also cannot work, as some valid records can have also those, like the first row, that logically cannot be a subtotal. And yes, checking the table in the UI i know this first result is a record. But doing this in Apex seems tricky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case for using the Grouping function:

```
SELECT LeadSource, Rating,
    GROUPING(LeadSource) grpLS, GROUPING(Rating) grpRating,
    COUNT(Name) cName
FROM Lead
GROUP BY ROLLUP(LeadSource, Rating)
```

This will give you a result where grpLS and grpRating will indicate whether it's a grouping result by showing a 1 or a 0.

I.e.

- detail rows have grpLS=0, grpRating=0
- Subtotal rows have grpLS=0, grpRating=1
- Grand total row has grpLS=1, grpRating=1

See also https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_grouping.htm?q=grouping

Comment: Heck, learned something new today. I was going to go on about removing the final row and then using a Set to track when you see a new value of the first (leftmost) field in the `GROUP BY ROLLUP`. Nice to see Salesforce has a better way to do this.

Comment: Awesome: this was it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, still a question: what is the point of passing a GROUPING for  LeadSource? running that code, i see the grouping for Rating counts the nulls and record with values, but not for LeadSource. As if this `SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Lead
WHERE LeadSource = null` where returning 0, when i actually have a count of 9 here. While the subtotals of GROUPING(Rating) make total sense, the one for GROUPING(LeadSource) does not, as its all 0

Comment: The purpose of that is to be able to distinguish the Grand Total (last line) from the subtotals. In your example I think line 5 will be equal to the last line if you don't include GROUPING(LeadSource).